# How do make the list of facebook application users not show upon login

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I am using the javascript SDK as shown in the documentation, my issue that when the user logs in, a list of users that have already allowed the app shows in the position of the login button. Any one have any ideas as to why this happens and/or how to fix it.

edit: seems like its the facepile plugin, but i havent specifically enabled that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

oops, i had the data-show-faces attribute set.